# How do I generate Symfony fixtures YML from exising database data?

Tags: database, build, symfony1, yaml, fixtures

I was wondering if anyone knew how to generate a fixture.yml from data that is already existing in the database?

As you can use the build-schema to generate a schema, is there a way to do that for data?

```
symfony propel:build-schema
```

Comment: Why not to read carefully `symfony`'s output, eh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Symfony 1.0 use the command:

```
$ php symfony propel-dump-data  <APPLICATION_NAME> <FIXTURES_DIR_OR_FILE> [<ENVIRONMENT_NAME>]
```

In versions 1.1 and 1.2 use the following command:

```
$ php symfony propel:data-dump <APPLICATION_NAME> [<TARGET>] [--env=<ENVIRONMENT_NAME>]
```

Comment: the command not working, i am using Symfony1.2-propel. it is giving me error as "Execution failed  -Too many arguments <propel:data-dump projname fixtures.yml dev> given" please help!

Comment: @harish I think you forgot the "--env=" so it should be "--env=dev" not just "dev"

Comment: @Hendy Irawan need to check that but symfony propel:data-dump > fixture.yml worked for me..

Answer (score 12):

In symfony 1.4 you just need to write:

```
./symfony doctrine:data-dump
```

and you get the file `data/fixtures/data.yml`

:-)

Answer (score 6):

I found a [solution](http://www.mail-archive.com/symfony-users@googlegroups.com/msg13430.html) in a mail archive. The user uses

```
symfony propel:data-dump > fixture.yml
```

Comment: yeah! this code works... Thank u.. Felix, it creates fixture.yml file inside the root folder.

Answer (score 5):

I just had to do this under symfony 1.2 and Doctrine.

symfony doctrine:data-dump

This dumps the entire database to data/fixtures/data.yml.  I had loaded some data to the database with a .sql file and wanted it as a fixture for my live database.  I just edited the data.yml file down to the database table I needed.

The alternative was to write some code to read the database table and output it in YAML format.